# Getting file_get_contents error - simple_html_dom.php XAMPP

Tags: php

The problem I am experiencing is below:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper &quot;https&quot; - 
did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in 
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\test_crawl\simple_html_dom.php</b> on line <b>75</b><br 
/>
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  file_get_contents(https://www.yahoo.com): failed to open 
stream: Invalid argument in 
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\test_crawl\simple_html_dom.php</b> on line <b>75</b><br 
 />
```

I did some research and I found a few posts that said uncommenting `extension=php_openssl.dll` in `php.ini` works but when I did and restarted my server it did not.The script I am used is below:

```
$url = 'https://yahoo.com'
function CrawlMe($url)
{
$html = file_get_html($url);
return json_encode($html);
}
```

Not sure why it's not working would appreciate your help..

Below is the function that's erroring out at `$contents = file_get_contents($url, $use_include_path, $context, $offset);`

```
function file_get_html($url, $use_include_path = false, $context=null, 
$offset = -1, $maxLen=-1, $lowercase = true, $forceTagsClosed=true, 
$target_charset = DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET, $stripRN=true, 
$defaultBRText=DEFAULT_BR_TEXT, $defaultSpanText=DEFAULT_SPAN_TEXT)
{
// We DO force the tags to be terminated.
$dom = new simple_html_dom(null, $lowercase, $forceTagsClosed, 
$target_charset, $stripRN, $defaultBRText, $defaultSpanText);
// For sourceforge users: uncomment the next line and comment the 
// retreive_url_contents line 2 lines down if it is not already done.
$contents = file_get_contents($url, $use_include_path, $context, $offset);
// Paperg - use our own mechanism for getting the contents as we want to 
control the timeout.
//$contents = retrieve_url_contents($url);
if (empty($contents) || strlen($contents) > MAX_FILE_SIZE)
{
    return false;
}
// The second parameter can force the selectors to all be lowercase.
$dom->load($contents, $lowercase, $stripRN);
return $dom;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whats on line 75 of simple_html_dom.php? From what you have posted all I can say is

```
$url = 'https://yahoo.com'
```

is missing a semi colon, it should be:

```
$url = 'https://yahoo.com';
```

--Edit after seeing the code...

You are setting the offset to -1. which means start reading from the end of the file. As per the documentation

> Seeking (offset) is not supported with remote files. Attempting to
>   seek on non-local files may work with small offsets, but this is
>   unpredictable because it works on the buffered stream.

Your maxlength is set to minus 1. As per the documaentation:

> An E_WARNING level error is generated if filename cannot be found,
>   maxlength is less than zero, or if seeking to the specified offset in
>   the stream fails.

You don't need to specify all those parameters, this will work fine:

```
$file = file_get_contents('https://www.yahoo.com');
```

Comment: line 75: `$contents = file_get_contents($url, $use_include_path, $context, $offset);`

Comment: ...and what are those variables set to? It's going to be much easier if you just post all the code.

Comment: here is the [function definition](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c86f20d4667405d27ac212a1130b9a857468e74a)